# SQL Subconsultas

Tags: sql, subconsultas

Tengo un problema con el siguiente ejercicio de SQL, Tengo que usar subconsultas y Utilizar la base de datos northwind ,dice lo siguiente:

**16.   De la orden número 10251. Mostrar Nombre del Empleado, Nombre de la compañía, fecha de la orden, nombre de cada producto, cantidad y precio unitario y precio final (= unitprice * quantity – unitprice*quantity*discount)**

Pude llegar  a lo siguiente, probé cada subconsulta por separada y devuelve el valor esperada el problema surge al querer ejecutar todas juntas, en la misma consulta

```
select 
(select FirstName from Employees where EmployeeID=Orders.EmployeeID)as 'Name',
(select Customers.CompanyName from Customers where  Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID)'Company name' ,
(select   Products.ProductName,Products.UnitPrice,[Order Details].Quantity,(Products.UnitPrice*[Order Details].Quantity-Products.UnitPrice*[Order Details].Quantity*[Order Details].Discount)AS 'Final Price' from Products INNER JOIN [Order Details] on Products.ProductID= [Order Details].ProductID WHERE [Order Details].OrderID=10251),
Orders.OrderDate
from Orders 
where OrderID=10251
```

Comment: Deberias poner en la pregunta la estructura de BD que estas usando para poder analizar mejor que es lo que intentas.

Comment: El ejercicio esta basado en la base de datos de prueba de Microsoft **Northwind**

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! No todos tienen acceso a northwind, en tu pregunta deberia estar la estructura de las tablas y un set de datos de prueba

Comment: Y cual es el problema que surge?

Answer (score 1):

No queda claro cual es el problema con tu query. Como bien indicaron en los comentarios deberías comaprtir la estructura de las tablas involucradas, juntos con un [conjunto mínimo de datos de prueba](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), junto con el resultado deseado.

En lugar de utilizar tantas subqueries, yo escribiría la query de esta forma (vinculando las tablas en la query principal directamente):

Es posible que la query falle, ya que no la he podido probar, pero te servirá de modelo para construir la query que necesitas. Yo me basé en la información que está en tu query para construirla (ya que no cuento con la información del modelo de datos).

```
SELECT e.FirstName AS employee_name,
       c.CompanyName AS company_name,
       o.OrderDate,
       p.ProductName,
       od.Quantity,
       p.UnitPrice,
       (p.UnitPrice * od.Quantity) - (p.UnitPrice * od.Quantity * od.Discount) AS final_price 
       
FROM Orders o
INNER JOIN Employees e ON e.EmployeeID = o.EmployeeID
INNER JOIN Customers c ON c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
INNER JOIN [Order Details] od ON od.OrderID = o.OrderID
INNER JOIN Products p ON p.ProductID = od.ProductID
WHERE o.OrderID = 10251;
```